# Apache Impala group by and order by together

Tags: sql, impala

I am new to apache impala. working on building the query.

here is the sample data.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| id_ingredient | ingredient_name | price |  timestamp | deleted |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1      | potatoes        | 10.00 | 1445899655 |    0    |
|        2      | tomatoes        | 20.00 | 1445836421 |    0    |
|        1      | sweet potatoes  | 10.00 | 1445899132 |    0    |
|        1      | sweet potatoes  | 15.00 | 1445959231 |    0    |
|        2      | tomatoes        | 30.00 | 1445894337 |    1    |
|        3      | chicken         | 50.00 | 1445899655 |    0    |
```

I want to build the table that shows only the most recent state of each ingredient that has not been yet deleted.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a group by

```
select ingredient_name , max(timestamp) 
from my_table
where deleted = 0
group by ingredient_name
```

of for retrieve the entire row = could

```
select * from my_table 
inner join  (
select ingredient_name , max(timestamp) 
from my_table a
where deleted = 0
group by ingredient_name ) t on t.ingredient_name  =a.ingredient_name  
       and t.timestamp = a.timestamp
```

Comment: just one stupid question.
`ingredient_name` will select the first name ?
i am bit consufe with output.

Comment: what do you mean with "will select the first name"   .. explain better  please

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption is that `deleted` would only be on the most recent state, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ingredient_name order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and deleted = 0;
```